# Material UI, target button variant css selector

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I created 3 classes that apply a gradient for each type material UI button variant. The classes are: `gradient`, `outlinedGradient`, and `containedGradient`,

[image]

But I wanted to just create one class `gradient` and then create more specific selectors for when the button is the Material UI's default, outlined, or contained button so I don't have to manually change the gradient class when I change the button styles.

I tried using the selectors `"& .MuiButton-contained":` and `& .MuiButton-outlined` but the styles didn't get applied.

[image]

Not working:

```js
const styles = (theme) => ({
  root: {
    padding: theme.spacing.unit
  },
  button: { margin: theme.spacing.unit },
  gradient: {
    background: theme.palette.primary.mainGradient,
    "-webkitBackgroundClip": "text",
    "-webkitTextFillColor": "transparent",
    "& .MuiButton-contained": {
      "-webkitBackgroundClip": "unset",
      "-webkitTextFillColor": "black"
    },
   "& .MuiButton-outlined": {
     ...more styles
    }
  }
});
```

CodeSandbox:

- [3 classes](https://codesandbox.io/s/gradient-material-ui-0x6x6?file=/src/PreviewButton.js) working
- [1 class](https://codesandbox.io/s/gradient-material-ui-attempt-one-class-s4vjg?file=/src/PreviewButton.js:395-418) not working

Is it possible to do this? To target these button variants in the css in material UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59958892/how-to-target-button-base-with-material-ui-and-styled-components)

> You are referencing the CSS class using a descendant selector, but MuiButtonBase-root is on the root element (i.e. the same element that the styled-components class name will be applied to) so the appropriate syntax is &.MuiButtonBase-root (without the space after the ampersand).

I just had to leave out the space in the selectors `"&.MuiButton-contained"` not `"& .MuiButton-contained"`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply your own style to the MUI components, first you have to disable the default style by using the disable method. i found the answer [here]. [1](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/)
like this

```
<Button disable id="button"></Button>
```